# Type 'String' cannot be used as an index type when adding key/val pair to object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm using Typescript and React for my project and I'm getting this error:

```
const dataKey: String
Type 'String' cannot be used as an index type. ts(2538)
```

And here is my code (simplified):

```
export interface UserData {
  email: string;
  name: string;
  buyer: boolean;
}

createObject(data: any) {
  const dataObj: UserData = {
    email: '',
    name: '',
    buyer: '',
  };

  for (const i in data) {
    const dataKey: String = data[i].field.toLowerCase();
    dataObj[dataKey] = data[i].value;
  }
  return dataObj;
}
```

I don't know how else I could be adding key/value pairs to my dataObj without using a string value as they key here. I have to perform that lowercase string manipulation on they dataKey.

Does anyone know how I can rework this bit of my code?

Comment: Have you tried as `string` instead of `String`?

Comment: I have tried that but then I get another related error on the same line: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'UserData'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'UserData'. ts(7053)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite `String` as `string`.  The former is an object; the latter is a primitive.  You want to use a primitive `string` as a key, not an object for the key.

For instance:

```js
String('foo') // object of type String
'foo' // string
```

Also rewrite this:

```js
export interface UserData {
  email: string;
  name: string;
  buyer: boolean;
}
```

As this:

```js
export interface UserData {
  [key: string]: string | boolean,
  email: string;
  name: string;
  buyer: boolean;
}
```

So that TypeScript allows you to use computed property names.

Comment: I tried this but then I get an error on the same line. `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'UserData'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'UserData'. ts(7053)`